# is it possible to do internal routing using <routeroutlet> in 2 tabs while using ng-bootstrap tabs

Tags: angular, tabs, ng-bootstrap, angular-ui-tabset

We want to implement 2 tabs using ng-bootstrap tabs without destroying content while switching. We want to use internal routing using . 
Is it possible?
The issue that we could anticipate is that URL gets lost as soon as we do the internal routing in another tab and once we click on previous tab the relevant path in internal routing does not match.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is better to backup your question with the efforts you have made and the code sample you are working on. It will help everyone understand your problem in a better way. cheers!

Comment: Why do you want to use internal routing for such a purpose? Can't you just use a custom component in each ng-bootstrap tab without providing a route for the tabs?